# SharePoint 2010 and Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, sharepoint-2010

I have a problem with .eml files that I open from a SharePoint list.

Let me give some background first then describe the problem.

We have various lists in our business that each have their own email address to receive query's from customers. We have set SharePoint to permissive to allow the users to view the item in the list which displays the content of the email but it also attaches the originalmessage.eml file which can be clicked on and IE then asks if you want to save and open, we open them so it opens in outlook 2010 for which we can then reply to the email.

This works fine but recently we had an issue where it would open the .eml file in a new IE tab, not useful as you can't reply. I fixed this by deleting any reference to message rfc 822 in the registry this allowed the .eml to be opened in Outlook 2010 again.

The problem is now that when a user opens an .eml file it saves a copy of the email into the users inbox in Outlook when it never did before.

Users seem to relate this happening from when they put on their out of office reply on.

It doesn't happen to everyone, it doesn't happen for every list we have and it doesn't happen to me and I use Office 2013 64 bit.

If it's down to the message rfc 822 I will have to manually re add them as a rebuild of the amount of users who have this problem will be too much.

I was wondering if anyone anywhere knows any smidgen of info about this please.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have finally figured out what the problem was.

Our workstations all had Symantec Endpoint Anti Virus protection on them which I have been changing to ESET Endpoint Anti Virus, it was the Outlook add-in that caused the issue.

All I did was to apply a policy through the ESET Administration console that disables the add-in then reapplied my domain policy which re enables it and it has cleared the problem.